# How to add gradient to a shape drawn with Custom Painter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a design found on Dribbble which looks like this:

[image]

What I have been able to make till now looks like:

[image]

I have made this design in Flutter using the below code:

```dart
Path rectPathThree = Path();
rectPathThree.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
rectPathThree.lineTo(size.width * 0.6, size.height);
rectPathThree.lineTo(size.width * 0.8, size.height);
rectPathThree.lineTo(size.width, size.height * 0.5);
rectPathThree.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
rectPathThree.close();
```

This isn't the complete code but just part of it, the rest of the design is also made in the same way using `lineTo`

To draw it to canvas:

```dart
paint.color = lightColorTwo;
canvas.drawPath(rectPathThree, paint);
```

The original design contains a bit white on top and then starts merging towards the base color at the bottom. How to add such gradient?

Comment: check `Paint.shader` and various modes of `BlendMode` enum

Comment: @pskink Can you post an example? I couldn't find much on it except a couple of Stack Overflow links with Arc Gradient.

Comment: `var _p = Paint()..color = Colors.green;
    var rect = Rect.fromPoints(offset, offset + Offset(200, 200));
    var rrect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(30));
    canvas.drawRRect(rrect, _p);

    _p.shader = LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topRight,
      end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      colors: [Colors.white.withOpacity(0.66), Colors.transparent],
    ).createShader(rect);
    canvas.drawRRect(rrect, _p..blendMode = BlendMode.overlay);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of defining a color, define a shader. It will give you the gradient you are looking for:

```
var rect = Offset.zero & size;
Path rectPathThree = Path();
Paint paint = Paint();
paint.shader = LinearGradient(
  begin: Alignment.topRight,
  end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
  colors: [
    Colors.blue[900],
    Colors.blue[500],
  ],
).createShader(rect);
```

Comment: Perfect solution..!

Comment: @j-s can you please explain what is happening in the first line? I'm not sure how a Rect is being created here.

Comment: This code follows the OPs code. That's where the `size` variable comes from, and the `rect` variable is used on the last line.